# Binary tree without pointers

Tags: binary-tree

Below is a representation of a binary tree that I use in my project. In the bottom are the leaf nodes (orange boxes), and every level is the sum of the children below.

So, 3 on the leftmost node is the sum of 1 and 2 (it's left and right children), 10 is the sum of 3 and 7 (again left and right children).

What I am trying to do is, store this tree in a flat array without using any pointers. So this array is basically an integer array, holding 2n-1 nodes (n is the number of the leaf nodes).

So the index of the root element is 0 (let's call it p), and the index of it's left child is 2p+1, index of the right child is 2p+2. Please see [Binary Tree (Array implementation)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-array-implementation/)

Everything works nicely if I know the number of leaf values beforehand but I can't seem to find a way to store this tree in a dynamically expanding array.

If I need to add 9 for example as the 9th element to the array, the structure needs to change and I need to recalculate all the indices again which I refrain because there may be hundreds of thousand of elements in the array at any time.

Does anyone know of an implementation that handles dynamic arrays with this implementation?

[image: Binary tree]

EDIT:

Below is the demonstration of what happens when I add new elements to the array. 36 was the root before, now it's a second level element and the new root array[0] is 114, which triggers a new layout.

[image]

Comment: Your formulas above for getting the indexes of a node's children do not rely on the size of the array, so in an expanded array (to allow for a larger tree) all the existing child indexes would remain the same, no?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Please see the edit.

Comment: Might this link help you:
https://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1d/ods-java/node52.html

Comment: Normally, storing a binary tree in an array is compatible with expanding the array without modifying any index. Could you be more specific (it seems you are trying to build a particular type of tree)? Also, I do not understand, in your second figure, why the node with the value `26` has 2 parents.

Comment: @m.raynal Sorry about that, uploaded the correct image.

Comment: Simply put, any time you wish to add a leaf to the tree, you'll need to update the values of all its ancestors nodes. The fact that the previous root had the value `36` and that after adding several nodes, another node ends up having the value 36 are disconnected. Updating the value of a node ancestor can be done in `log n` though.